# how to keep the alarm stay in red when the signal send from a machine that keep changing btw 1 and 0?

Tags: c#, timer, alarm

i have a code that using to indicate the alarm from a machine, and the alarm of the machine will be flash to show when the machine facing some problem...

when it flashing the alarm, the output will be keep changing between 1 and 0. and of course my visual C# will write a if else statement to show that the alarm is ringing, if alarm=1, then alarm picture will become red, else alarm=0, then alarm picture will become green.

but when receive the signal from the machine was flash between 1 and 0, and my alarm picture  at the visual c# will also keep changing between red and green, what could i do so that when the alarm is flashing, and my alarm picture in visual c# just keep showing red? because i need to store in the database too once alarm is sound.
here is my if else statement...

```
if (bn4 == "1" || bn4 == "0")
{   
    if ((cmdstop4 == 1) || bn4 == "0")
    {
        alarm.Stop();
        pictureBox6.Show();
        pictureBox14.Hide();
        bn4 = "0";

    }
    if (bn4 == "1")
    {
        alarm.PlayLooping();
        pictureBox14.Show();
        pictureBox6.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be way easier when the variable names in your code would be meaningful. What should bn4 be and how will it change? Please add all the relevant code.

Comment: bn4 is the signal send from the machine.. and cmdstop4 is the stop button that use to stop the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sentinal value to determine if the alarm has been previously triggered. It doesn't need to be complex, just an int set to 0 if the alarm is off and 1 if the alarm has been triggered.

```
// this sentinal should be declared somewhere useful, in the alarm would make most sense 
int alarmTriggered = 0; 

if (bn4 == "1" || bn4 == "0") 
{    
    if ((cmdstop4 == 1) || (alarmTriggered == 0 && bn4 == "0")) 
    { 
        alarmTriggered = 0;
        alarm.Stop(); 
        pictureBox6.Show(); 
        pictureBox14.Hide(); 
        bn4 = "0"; 

    } 
    if (bn4 == "1" || alarmTriggered == 1) 
    { 
        alarmTriggered = 1;
        alarm.PlayLooping(); 
        pictureBox14.Show(); 
        pictureBox6.Hide(); 
    } 
}
```